# asp.net web service return invalid XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap, asmx

i have a web service its run locally, but when i hosted on AWS its not running from my client I get the error "System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML ..."

I tried to call it from SoapUI its working

this is the request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:her="http://HerakiNet.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <her:SayHello>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <her:name>Ahmed</her:name>
      </her:SayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the response as raw:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 29 Dec 2013 11:12:39 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 359
X-Cache: MISS from UB15-WMJ-080811
Via: 1.1 UB15-WMJ-080811:3128 (Lusca)
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><SayHelloResponse xmlns="http://HerakiNet.com/"><SayHelloResult>Hello , Ahmed</SayHelloResult></SayHelloResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

can any one help??

this is the result of executing a small test from DotNet App:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: There is a problem with the XML that was
>   received from the network. See inner exception for more details. ---> System.Xml
>   .XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 ...

the application code is:

```
var client = new EstimatorWcfService.EstimatorWebServiceSoapClient();
Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello("Ahmed"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: The XML looks valid to me, what's are the exact details of the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

According to error, you are calling wrong end point url from your client.
There would be two urls in service tag in your wsdl one for http and another for https. May be you are using https one instead of http. Cross check from soap ui (at top of your request).